# WebUI.getText() may return empty string, even if the TestObject is found and has `innerText != ”`

Tags: selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

### Runtime environment

I am on Katalon Studio 8.6.0, on a Windows 11 machine.

### Thesis

For some reason, `WebUI.getText()` may return null/empty, even though there exist some `innerText` in the web element on the page...

I have this `BaseScrollableSelectionStrategy` that `doSelect(dropdownOption)` by scrolling to the last available dropdown option, and then to the `dropdownOption` itself, until the wait for it is complete.

This is used on a CRM autocomplete, which inserts the next "page" of dropdown options (or any other widget) on scroll past current page). Hence, last avaiable dropdown option is subject to change once we scroll to it (because the app fetches the next "page" of dropdown options after that).

its `doSelect` is defined to be:

```
public void doSelect(TestObject dropdownOption) {
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ActionHandler.HandleFailableAction({
        this.waitForDropdownOption(dropdownOption);
    }, { boolean success, _ ->
        KeywordUtil.logInfo("${dropdownOption.getObjectId()} ${this.getActionStatus(success, startTime)}")
        if (!success) {
            final TestObject lastAvailableDropdownItem = new TestObject("Last available dropdown item")
                .addProperty("xpath",
                    ConditionType.EQUALS,
                    "//lyte-drop-box[not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' lyteDropdownHidden '))]//lyte-drop-item[last()]");

            TimeLoggerUtil.LogAction({
                if (!WebUI.waitForElementPresent(lastAvailableDropdownItem, 2))
                    return false;

                GeneralWebUIUtils.ScrollDropdownOptionIntoView(lastAvailableDropdownItem);

                return true;
            }, lastAvailableDropdownItem.getObjectId(),
            "scroll into view");
        }
    }, 15)
    GeneralWebUIUtils.ScrollDropdownOptionIntoView(dropdownOption);
    WebUI.click(dropdownOption);
}
```

When we `GeneralWebUIUtils.ScrollDropdownOptionIntoView()`, we're doing:

```
public static void ScrollDropdownOptionIntoView(TestObject to) {
    WebUI.executeJavaScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'})", [WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(to, 3)]);

    WebUI.waitForElementNotPresent(to, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL);
    WebUI.waitForElementVisible(to, 2);
}
```

### The issue

When I run a test suite full of test cases that deal with these kind of autocomplete dropdown options (and use this `BaseScrollableSelectionStrategy` to handle them), it **runs out the entire 15+ seconds of time passed to `ActionHandler.HandleFailableAction()`**!

The `onAction` (first) callback fails the whole time! It ends up calling the following general WebUI util method:

```
public static boolean WaitForElementTextMatches(TestObject to, String expectedText, int timeOut, FailureHandling failureHandling = FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE) {
    return this.WaitForElementCondition({ TestObject testObj ->
        String testObjectText = WebUI.getText(testObj);
        
        return testObjectText.equals(expectedText);
    }, { boolean success, TestObject testObj ->
        if (success)
            return;

        if (WebUI.waitForElementNotPresent(testObj, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)) { 
            WebUI.waitForElementPresent(testObj, timeOut);
        }
        if (WebUI.verifyElementPresent(testObj, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL))
            KeywordUtil.logInfo("TestObject '${testObj.getObjectId()}' is now present!")
        
        if (WebUI.waitForElementVisible(testObj, timeOut, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL))
            KeywordUtil.logInfo("TestObject '${testObj.getObjectId()}' has text '${WebUI.getText(testObj)}'")
    },
    to,
    timeOut,
    failureHandling);
}
```

To add insult to injury, **the element may end up present, but is NEVER visible, according to Katalon/Selenium**!

I see

```
TestObject 'Object Repository/Page_Create Member Lead - Zoho CRM/Member Lead Information Section/Member Category autocomplete/Membership dropdown option' is now present!
```

but NEVER

```
TestObject 'Object Repository/Page_Create Member Lead - Zoho CRM/Member Lead Information Section/Member Category autocomplete/Membership dropdown option' has text
```

...

### HTML or GTFO

After the scroll, the dropdown list HTML looks like:

```
<lyte-drop-box
  class="w100per createAutocomplete alyteautocompleteDropdown undefined lyteDropdownDown lyteDropboxRightAlignToButton"
  style="position: absolute; width: 388px; min-width: 388px; top: 1703.34px; left: 251px;"
>
  <span class="lyteArrow" style="width: 388px;"></span>
  <div
    class="w100per h5 m0"
    mouseout="crm-create-fields => setFullViewRec(event,false)"
    mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setFullViewRec"
  ></div>
  <lyte-drop-body
    role="listbox"
    id="Lyte_Drop_Body_34"
    lyte-rendered-ce=""
    style="max-height: 250px; width: auto;"
    class="lyteScrollBar"
  >
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000074126386"
      data-value="4623170000074126386"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_23"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
      class=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Child Membership - Option B </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000074126386"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000074124524"
      data-value="4623170000074124524"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_24"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Child Membership - Option D </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000074124524"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000074067550"
      data-value="4623170000074067550"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_25"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Child Membership - Option A </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000074067550"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000056764203"
      data-value="4623170000056764203"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_26"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Membership - Option F </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000056764203"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000056748147"
      data-value="4623170000056748147"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_27"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Membership - Option G </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000056748147"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000035961028"
      data-value="4623170000035961028"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_28"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Membership - Option E </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000035961028"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000035914031"
      data-value="4623170000035914031"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_29"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Membership - Option C </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000035914031"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000035905010"
      data-value="4623170000035905010"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_30"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Membership - Option D </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000035905010"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000035889035"
      data-value="4623170000035889035"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_31"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Membership - Option B </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000035889035"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000035827103"
      data-value="4623170000035827103"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_32"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Membership - Option A </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000035827103"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000026970010"
      data-value="4623170000026970010"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_33"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Corporate Membership </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000026970010"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000014601011"
      data-value="4623170000014601011"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_35"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Child Membership </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000014601011"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000014583083"
      data-value="4623170000014583083"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_36"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Standard Membership </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000014583083"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000014576015"
      data-value="4623170000014576015"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_37"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Gold Membership </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000014576015"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000014557044"
      data-value="4623170000014557044"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_38"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Membership </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000014557044"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <lyte-drop-item
      data-zcqa="Member Category_4623170000014541068"
      data-value="4623170000014541068"
      aria-selected="false"
      role="option"
      id="Lyte_Drop_Item_39"
      lyte-rendered-ce=""
    >
      <lyte-autocomplete-label aria-selected="false"
        ><span
          class="lookup-autoc-text"
          lt-prop-tooltip-class="lcreateTooltip"
          lt-prop-tooltip-config='{"position" : "followcursor","margin" : "10","hidedelay" : "50"}'
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setLookupTooltip"
          >Silver Membership </span
        ><i
          id="4623170000014541068"
          class="info_icon infoIcoLookupAuto cP fR vh"
          mouseout="crm-create-fields => infoPop(this,val,event)"
          mouseenter="crm-create-fields => infoPop"
          ><crmutil-icon
            icon-name="info-solid"
            icon-class="zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon"
            lyte-rendered=""
          >
            <svg class="zcicn_embedSvg zcicn-info-solid crmBaseIcon">
              <use href="#zcicn-info-solid"></use>
            </svg> </crmutil-icon
        ></i>
      </lyte-autocomplete-label>
    </lyte-drop-item>
    <div class="lyteDropdownNoResult" style="display: none;">
      No Results Found
    </div></lyte-drop-body
  >
  <span
    id="Crm_Potentials_POTENTIALCF04_load_img"
    class="lookupTxtOverflow pL20 pR20 dN"
  >
    <img
      class="mB6 dIB"
      alt="loading"
      src="//img.zohocdn.com/crm/images/loading_599c9b1_.gif"
    />
  </span>
  <div
    class="w100per h5 m0"
    mouseout="crm-create-fields => setFullViewRec(event,false)"
    mouseenter="crm-create-fields => setFullViewRec"
  ></div>
  <lyte-drop-footer>
    <div
      data-zcqa="AddNewRecord"
      class="dropFooterList alignLeft pL25"
      click="crm-create-fields => newAction()"
    >
      New Member Category
    </div>
  </lyte-drop-footer>
  <div class="lyteautocompleteError noErrClass" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div
    class="lyteScrollContainer lyteScrollContainerY"
    style="visibility: hidden;"
  >
    <div
      class="lyteScrollDiv"
      style="height: 161.392px; transform: translateY(93.6076px);"
    ></div>
  </div>
  <div
    class="lyteScrollContainer lyteScrollContainerX"
    style="visibility: hidden;"
  >
    <div class="lyteScrollDiv"></div></div
></lyte-drop-box>
```

**Before the scroll**, the dropdown list contains up to the *Corporate Membership* dropdown item.
**After the scroll**, we see the *Corporate Membership* dropdown item in the viewport, and **the whole list is available**.

[image: the drop-down list]

### What have I tried about this problem

I modified my `onCheckCondition` (first) callback inside the util method, to get the text via JavaScript if `WebUI.getText(to)` is `null` or `''`. Here's what the method looks like now:

```
public static boolean WaitForElementTextMatches(TestObject to, String expectedText, int timeOut, FailureHandling failureHandling = FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE) {
    return this.WaitForElementCondition({ TestObject testObj ->
        String testObjectText = WebUI.getText(testObj);
        if (SMDStringUtils.IsNullOrEmpty(testObjectText))
            testObjectText = (String)WebUI.executeJavaScript('return arguments[0].innerText', [WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(testObj, 1)]);  
        
        return testObjectText.equals(expectedText);
    }, { boolean success, TestObject testObj ->
        if (success)
            return;

        if (WebUI.waitForElementNotPresent(testObj, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)) { 
            WebUI.waitForElementPresent(testObj, timeOut);
        }
        
        if (WebUI.waitForElementVisible(testObj, timeOut, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL))
            KeywordUtil.logInfo("TestObject '${testObj.getObjectId()}' has text '${WebUI.getText(testObj)}'")
    },
    to,
    timeOut,
    failureHandling);
}
```

I run it, and **the hanging problem goes away**! I don't even have to change up anything else!!

### OK, but what's the problem, Mike?!

The problem is that `WebUI.getText(testObject)`, and the `element.getText()` that happens behind the scene, **may return some empty string**, despite the HTML element may be in the DOM, already waited on by the testing code, **it has some `innerText`**, and the test may have found it.

**What causes this to happen?!**